# Safely executing user-submitted python code on the server

Tags: python, user-input

I am looking into starting a project which involves executing python code that the user enters via a HTML form. I know this can be potentially lethal (`exec`), but I have seen it done successfully in at least [one instance](http://challenge.ncss.edu.au/).

I sent an email off to the developers of the [Python Challenge](http://challenge.ncss.edu.au/) and I was told they are using a solution they came up with themselves, and they only let on that they are using "security features provided by the operating system" and that "the operating system [Linux] provides most of the security you need if you know how to use it."

Would anyone know how a safe and secure way to go about doing this? I thought about spawning a new VM for every submission, but that would have way too much overhead and be pert-near impossible to implement efficiently.

Comment: Come to think of it... isn't this question better suited for SF (or perhaps SU)?

Comment: @Stephan202: not necesarily, because this *is* a **programming** problem.

Comment: how did you end up doing it?

Answer (score 3):

On a modern Linux in addition to chroot(2) you can restrict process further by using clone(2) instead of fork(2). There are several interesting clone(2) flags:

```
CLONE_NEWIPC (new namespace for semaphores, shared memory, message queues)
CLONE_NEWNET (new network namespace - nice one)
CLONE_NEWNS (new set of mountpoints)
CLONE_NEWPID (new set of process identifiers)
CLONE_NEWUTS (new hostname, domainname, etc)
```

Previously this functionality was implemented in OpenVZ and merged then upstream, so there is no need for patched kernel anymore.

Answer (score 3):

http://codepad.org/about has implemented such a system successfully (as a public code pasting/running service!)

> codepad.org is an online compiler/interpreter, and a simple collaboration tool. It's a pastebin that executes code for you. [...]
>
> **How it works**
>
> Code execution is handled by a supervisor based on [geordi](http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/geordi/). The strategy is to run everything under ptrace, with many system calls disallowed or ignored. Compilers and final executables are both executed in a chroot jail, with strict resource limits. The supervisor is written in Haskell.
>
> [...]
>
> When your app is remote code execution, you have to expect security problems. Rather than rely on just the chroot and ptrace supervisor, I've taken some additional precautions:
>
> - The supervisor processes run on virtual machines, which are firewalled such that they are incapable of making outgoing connections.
> - The machines that run the virtual machines are also heavily firewalled, and restored from their source images periodically.

Answer (score 2):

If you run the script as user `nobody` (on Linux), it can write practically nowhere and read no data that has its permissions set up properly. But it could still cause a DoS attack by, for example:

- filling up `/tmp`
- eating all RAM
- eating all CPU

Furthermore, outside network connections can be opened, etcetera etcetera. You can probably lock all these down with kernel limits, but you are bound to forget something.

So I think that a virtual machine with no access to the network or the real hard drive would be the only (reasonably) safe route. Perhaps the developers of the Python Challenge use [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Main_Page) which is, in principle, "provided by the operating system".

For efficiency, you could run all submissions in the same VM. That saves you much overhead, and in the worst-case scenario they only hamper each other, but not your server.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`chroot`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot)) may be part of the solution, e.g. combined with [`ulimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ulimit) and some other common (or custom) tools.